# Parse Server: bad key in untransform: __v

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, keystonejs

I'm trying to access data with Parse server that was written into the MongoDB with the KeystoneJS CMS. The problem is that documents look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57caa222f322ce836e0a9002"),
    "title" : "Test for Parse",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

So I get this error: `Uncaught internal server error. bad key in untransform: __v`
Also, Parse server uses another format for the _id, String not ObjectId: `"_id" : "rbCGTfXLbJ"`

Is it somehow possible to make Parse server work with this data format? My idea is to use the same schema with both frameworks and so be able to "share" the data.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is a virtual function called id so _id will not disturb you much.

and for __v . you can disable it by setting mongoose option versionKey to false.

```
{versionKey: false}
```